# Groups - Proof that $(ab)^{-1} = b^{-1}a^{-1}$

Tags: group-theory

I read this proof in a book:

> Prove that if $a, b \in G$, then $(ab)^{-1} = b^{-1}a^{-1}$.
>
> Proof: Let $a,b \in G$. Then $abb^{-1}a^{-1} = aea^{-1} = aa^{-1} = e$. Also, $b^{-1}a^{-1}ab = e$. Because inverses are unique $(ab)^{-1} = b^{-1}a^{-1}$ follows.

I don't really understand this proof; I don't quite follow the logic. Where is the connection made between $(ab)^{-1}$ and $b^{-1}a^{-1}$?

Comment: which part are you confused?

Comment: One shows that $ab\cdot x=x\cdot ab=e$. So $x$ must be the inverse of $ab$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The argument essentially goes: If $x$ satisfies
$$(ab)\cdot x=e$$
then $x$ is the inverse of $ab$. That is essentially the definition of an inverse - and, by the properties of a group, defines a unique $x$. The proof says:

> Suppose $x=b^{-1}a^{-1}$. Then
>   $$(ab)\cdot x = abb^{-1}a^{-1}=aa^{-1}=e$$
>   hence $x=b^{-1}a^{-1}$ is the inverse of $(ab)$.

That is to say, the proof "guesses" that $b^{-1}a^{-1}$ is the inverse of $ab$, and then verifies that this is correct by showing that this $x$ behaves like the inverse of $(ab)$ ought to.

Answer (score 3):

Le be $a,b\in G$. If $ab\cdot x=x\cdot ab=e$, then $x$ is the inverse of $ab$, denoted by casually $(ab)^{-1},$ and this inverse is unique.

So, look that

$$(ab)(b^{-1}a^{-1})=a(bb^{-1})a^{-1}=aea^{-1}=aa^{-1}=e.$$

Similarly,

$$(b^{-1}a^{-1})(ab)=e.$$

As the inverse is unique, then $(ab)^{-1}=b^{-1}a^{-1}.$